# What is the motive behind moving CORS to code in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

Based on tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Why Web API 2.2 decided to use `EnableCors` extension method and Attributes to add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' headers?

Why can't we just add them using the IIS configuration?

Comment: Maybe you have an Web API application not hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

By using IIS configuration, you can send hard-coded response headers that are going to be sent for all requests coming into that app. You will generally need more control in terms of opening up cross-origin requests for certain origins, methods, etc. Web API CORS enables that level of control.